# Percentage - How To Know The Original Value

Tags: percentages

I'm practicing for SAT, and encountered this question:

---

The graph below shows the percentage of American households that owned landline telephones from 2000 to 2006.

[image]

According to the data above, the percentage of American households with landline telephones in 2001 was what percent greater than the percentage of American households with landline telephones in 2005?

---

I know that such a question should be solved like this: Difference / Original.

So I solved it like this: (Percentage in **2001** - Percentage in **2005**) / Percentage in **2005**.

= (80 - 60) / 60 = 20 / 60 = 0.33 = **33%**.

But then when I reviewed the answers the right answer was: 25%. It said that 80 is the original number and not 60 so it becomes: 20 / 80 = 0.25 = **25%**.

My question is: **How to know which one is the original number?** (it's obvious in some questions but here it's so confusing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you calculated is correct. In context, your answer allows us to answer the question as: "According to the data above, the percentage of American households with landline telephones in 2001 was $33.3$ percent greater than the percentage of American households with landline telephones in 2005". Which makes sense as $80=60\times\left(1+\frac{33.3}{100}\right)$. But with the given answer we instead have $60=80\times\left(1-\frac{25}{100}\right)$ which does not answer the given question.

Comment: So do you mean that the answer provided by the website that I'm practicing on is wrong? And my answer is correct?

Comment: That seems to be the case. The answer provided by the website doesn't answer the given question.

Comment: Thank you, now I'm not confused anymore.